# Getting html5 video to work on my server

Tags: html, .htaccess, video, ogg

First of all sorry for asking something that has been asked many times before but I just cant seem to find the answer to my problem.

I have a site with several html5 videos, everything works locally but not on my server. 
All the videos are uploaded (in ogv,mp4,webm), the directory path is correct but the videos aren't showing up in any browser.

I have tried adding "AddType video/ogg .ogv" etc to my .htaccess file but that does nothing. If i put the .htaccess file anywhere other than the folder where my videos are, I get a page with "IISPassword The page cannot be displayed".
I have added all the required mime types to Cpanel but still nothing.

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Update: Videos are now showing up in Chrome but not FF or safari

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that rather than _adding_ entries to .htaccess, you need to _delete_ the .htaccess file. IIS seems to not play nicely with it. - https://www.google.com.au/search?q=IISPassword+The+page+cannot+be+displayed&oq=IISPassword+The+page+cannot+be+displayed&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I've tried that too but that doesnt seem to make any difference either. Is there any way I can edit IIS settings? Is this something I would need to do?

Comment: Dunno, don't like/use IIS. Sorry, can't do any more than (or even as much as) you can at this point.